# XML data can't be read by swf file when i publish it

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, actionscript-3, url

I am trying to read data from a URL `http://localhost:15979/default.aspx`.The output of the url is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GALLERY>
<IMAGE TITLE="abs">image1.jpg</IMAGE>
<IMAGE TITLE="iron">image2.jpg</IMAGE>
<IMAGE TITLE="shop">image3.jpg</IMAGE>
</GALLERY>
```

I fetch this values `into adobe flash cs`  with this code:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(); 
var XML_URL:String = "http://localhost:15979/default.aspx"; 
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
    trace("Data loaded."); 
    txtname.text=myXML.IMAGE[1].@TITLE;
}
```

So when i push `ctrl +enter` the swf file shows the result and every thing works fine ,but when i publish the `swf` file my XML file can't be read and the `myXML.IMAGE[1].@TITLE;` doesn't apear on the screen.another problem is when i changed the xml ,the changes don't apply in SWF file.

I changed the xml form to :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
<GALLERY>
<IMAGE TITLE="asas">image1.jpg</IMAGE>
<IMAGE TITLE="ssssss">image2.jpg</IMAGE>
<IMAGE TITLE="shop">image3.jpg</IMAGE>
</GALLERY>
```

But .fl file throws this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at _3333333333333333333333_fla::MainTimeline/xmlLoaded()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Comment: Yes, when you run your swf in Flash authoring (swf on your computer), it will be able to consume an XML from any domain.

XML gets blocked when the swf is on DomainA.com, and the xml is on DomainB.com UNLESS there's a cross domain policy that says it's ok for another domain to use the xml.

You have to substitute the proper urls in your code.

http://my.domain.com/dataxml.xml is an example url.

Note that my.domain.com is just an example, i set my owner domain in my file .fla.

Comment: I found this ,but i don't know what does it mean ?

Comment: I thought this is my problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066552/swf-not-updating-when-file-xml-and-swf-not-in-the-same-domain/25070801#25070801

Comment: cross domain policy:http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403679-crossdomain-file-loading

Comment: There should be one root element.

Comment: @ChongLipPhang i am so new in XML and flash could you please give me more details

Comment: There can only be one root element in an XML document. In your second XML document, there are two root elements: cross-domain-policy and GALLERY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally add a cross domain file to my project as you can see here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and i call this file in my flash file like this :

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost:15979/crossdomain.xml");
```

and every thing works fine .

Comment: Looks like you got it working.  By default, one domain can't "use" another domain's xml unless the xml has a cross-domain policy (says it's ok).